# Passing a variable in as a JQuery ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am passing an id into a function as a string.  I want to use that ID to then change the background color.  I have used:

```
$("#"+address).css("background-color", "#3399FF");
```

but it is not changing the background color and when I do a:

```
console.log($("#"+address).css("background-color"));
```

It is coming up as undefined.

How can I pass the variable address into jquery?

Thanks for your help.

Kevin

Comment: That syntax should be correct.  I believe the reason you're getting undefined when trying to get the background color is because it hasn't been explicitly set?  Silly question... have you actually tried your code to change the bg color of the element?  If so, are you sure you only have one element with that particular id?

Comment: What happens when you console.log(address);?

Comment: Try console.log(address); if it has a valid value for you.

Comment: What you have should work, are you sure '"#"+address' returns a valid identifier?

Comment: You'll need to add more information.  It's possible you're trying to access the "address" variable outside of scope.  Also, how are you obtaining and/or passing the "address" variable?  I might need to see the full code...

Comment: try adding the pound # selector to the variable before using it in the jqueyr $() selector.

Comment: address is the id of a <tr> in a table.  It is a street address for a location, it is unique and a console.log(address); shows the proper output.

Comment: the address variable is passed into the function.  it is showing up correctly.

Comment: the code in the table that I changing is:
 "<tr id ='" + Restaurants[k].address + "' bgcolor = '#3399FF'>

the same Restaurants[k].address is then passed into the function by an onClick event.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: What is an example address? jquery can't handle some chars (!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~), try using  address.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\$1');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here,

You say you are using and address as an id

```
1234 Any st.
```

by appending a #,

```
#1234 Any st.
```

The jquery selector becomes, find the element with ID 1234, then any children of type Any, then any children of type st with class ''.
Which looks like

```
<div id="1234">
  <any>
     <st/>
  </any>
</div>
```

You need to escape spaces, periods, hell everything here !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~

As per the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name), an id should

```
must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters,
digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").
```

So to escape a valid id use,

```
function jq(myid) { 
    return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\$1');
}
```

as per [HERE](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely the problem!

Answer (score 0):

A couple guesses:

1. `address` was not set correctly, and your *actual* query is being evaluated as `$('#')`
2. `$` is not set, or set as a different library, or completely undefined. (not as likely, as you didn't mention other errors)
3. `address` is set to an `id` value that doesn't exist: `$('#foo')` may not exist on the page where you need `$('#bar')`

Please post more code, and try running `console.log(address);` to make sure you're doing what you think you're supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think we would need to see an example of address to better help you.